# IE won't transition pseudo ::before when the content:'\f00d'; changes

Tags: css

I have some pseudo elements on list items using a css counter:

```
li {
    display: inline-block; // this kills the list prefixes
    counter-increment: step-count; // recreate with a simple counter
    //...snip
    &::before {
        content: counter(step-count);
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all 225ms ease-in-out;
        //...snip
 }
}
```

then I make some changes on :hover

```
li:hover {
  &::before {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #74bb74;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: '\f00c'; 
        //...snip
 }
}
```

This works as expected except for IE(all).

IE abandons all the transitions when the line:

```
 content: '\f00c';
```

is there. Remove that line and the transitions work, but the effect I need doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried excluding `content` from the `transition`, or maybe give it a delay like so `transition: all 225ms ease-in-out, content 0 linear 225ms;`?

Comment: Thanks - i tried that, and also tried being explicit about each properties transition individually, but no luck.

I may just put it down as a progressive enhancement when the browser supports it, and move on.

Comment: The `content` property is not transitionable.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. I don't the content to transition. I need the content to change, and other properties - background-color, transform etc to transition.

Changing the content value stops all other properties from transitioning.

Comment: Then you can't use `transition:all`. Just comma-separate the properties you **do** want to transition.

Comment: As stated, I tried  transitioning specific properties, e.g.

           transition: background-color 225ms ease-in-out;

this doesnt work when the :hover state changes the content at all.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but as a workaround maybe you could use two pseudo-elements, `::before` and `::after`, and switch between them by transitioning their `opacity` properties. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4g6zk2v5/1/).

Comment: Bumped upon the same bug, reported via MS Feedback hub. If anyone has an idea how to make it work in Edge, let me know please: https://jsfiddle.net/byznL8e2/